# How can i fetch if there are two different types are there in database ex-(type=1,type=2) same table

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have database table as os_dish
in that dish type=1 is tiffen // dishtype=2 is lunch//

> My error is only tiffen values are coming in both Tiffen And Lunch

i want to select multiple how can i do that this is my Tiffen code:

```
<div class="products-row">
    <?php $tq=$conn->query("select * from os_dish where dish_type=1");
        while ($tiffen = $tq->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"> 
            <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>" class="Foodmenu" value="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>" name="tifeen[]" hidden>
                <label for="<?php echo $tiffen['dish_name'];?>"><img src="img/dish/<?php echo $tiffen['dish_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

And this is my Luch code:

```
<div class="products-row">
    <?php $lq=$conn->query("select * from os_dish where dish_type=2");
        while ($lunch = $lq->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"> 
            <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="<?php echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>" class="FoodMenu" value="<?php  echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>" name="lunch[]" hidden>
                <label for="<?php echo $lunch['dish_name'];?>"><img src="img/dish/<?php echo $lunch['dish_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is all correct, one possibility is of database table column type used, try using dish_type=2 in single quote as dish_type='2' and same for dish_type='1'

Comment: It worked thank you. @Nitin

Comment: your welcome.. glad to help you